# is it possible to make a system SMS Based Query in Java

Tags: java, sms

is it possible to make a system SMS Based Query in Java?because im planning to try and make a System Based on java that has SMS Based query like when you send some sort of code to the system it replies also with a sms

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out twilio. Pretty great and can set up a cool chat bot type of thing either using some web server or amazon lambda. You can set a script so it will take certain inputs, do whatever code you want and send an output.

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
 import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class SmsSender {

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message
            .creator(new PhoneNumber("+14159352345"),  // to
                     new PhoneNumber("+14158141829"),  // from
                     "Where's Wallace?")
            .create();
}
```

}

Comment: so i have to register at twilio? what number will i use to send a text msg?

Comment: yes you have to register and actually pay a couple cents per message. There's also nexmo and plivio that are cheaper (<1 cent), but no free option unfortunately. After you register they assign you a number.